# Adding the 2D array list values to a string in python

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, list, multidimensional-array

I am trying to convert a 2D list into mongodb document format.
Below is my list

```
list1=[('New Mexico', 'NM', '2020-04-06', 686, 12), ('New Mexico', 'NM', '2020-07-07', 13727, 519)]
```

i want to convert this into below format

```
{'state':'New Mexico','State_code':'NM','Date':'2020-04-06','cases':686,'deaths':12}
```

i tried accessing the list but not able to get the above format
below is the code

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    for j in range(len(list1[i])):
        item={
            'state': list1[i][j],
            'state_code': list1[i][j],
            'date': list1[i][j],
            'cases': list1[i][j],
            'deaths': list1[i][j]
        }            
    print(item)
```

above code inserts same value to all them,may i know how to insert each value into each of them(such as state,state_code etc)

thanks in advance

Comment: "above code inserts same value to all them,may i know how to insert each value into each of them(such as state,state_code etc)" - what does this mean? Add an example & explain clearly in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would better assign items like below. No need for second loop. You must be sure however that all items in list1 have same length, namely all necessary values:

```
for i in list1:
        item={
            'state': i[0],
            'state_code': i[1],
            'date': i[2],
            'cases': i[3],
            'deaths': i[4]
        }            
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello **sumesh** as **rads** said you need to save results from every iteration. By doing a small change you can get end result

```
items = []
for i in list1:
    temp_item={
        'state': [i][0],
        'state_code': [i][1],
        'date': [i][2],
        'cases': [i][3],
        'deaths': [i][4]
    }
    items.append(temp_item)            
print(items)
```

I am just saving results from every iteration in temp_item and then appending them to the items list :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a nice and pythonic fashion using regular list comprehensions and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)-

```py
# Put the keys to associate with the values in order as they appear in the tuples inside list1
keys = ('state', 'State_code', 'Date', 'cases', 'deaths')
result = [dict(zip(keys, l)) for l in list1]
```

#### Output

```py
[{'state': 'New Mexico',
  'State_code': 'NM',
  'Date': '2020-04-06',
  'cases': 686,
  'deaths': 12},
 {'state': 'New Mexico',
  'State_code': 'NM',
  'Date': '2020-07-07',
  'cases': 13727,
  'deaths': 519}]
```